# Creating a database dump for specific tables and entries Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a database with hundreds of tables, what I need to do is export specified tables and insert statements for the data to one sql file.

The only statement I know can achieve this is

```
pg_dump -D -a -t zones_seq interway > /tmp/zones_seq.sql
```

Should I run this statement for each and every table or is there a way to run a similar statement to export all selected tables into one big sql big. The pg_dump above does not export the table schema only inserts, I need both

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 268, accepted):

Right from the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html): "*Multiple tables can be selected by writing multiple -t switches*"

So you need to list all of your tables

```
pg_dump --column-inserts -a -t zones_seq -t interway -t table_3 ... > /tmp/zones_seq.sql
```

Note that if you have several table with the same prefix (or suffix) you can also use wildcards to select them with the `-t` parameter:

"*Also, the table parameter is interpreted as a pattern according to the same rules used by psql's \d commands*"

Comment: the -T switch is the same way but used to exclude tables.  Might be useful if you need all but one or two tables etc.

Comment: The `-D` option seems to have disappeared in PG 9.1 onwards

Comment: The `-D` option was [removed in version 8.4](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/release-8-4.html#AEN98016). You have to use `--column-inserts` now instead.

Comment: Try pg_dump --host 127.0.0.1 --port 5432 --username "<username>" --column-inserts --verbose --file "/tmp/<filename.sql>" --table "^<regex>*" "<tablename>"

Comment: Beware `-a` options skips tables schema export – so remove that option if you need to export these tables on fresh database

Answer (score 38):

If those specific tables match a particular [pattern](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS), you can use that with the `-t` option in `pg_dump`.

```
pg_dump -D -a -t zones_seq -t interway -t "<pattern>" -f /tmp/zones_seq.sql <DBNAME>
```

For example to dump tables which start with "test", you can use

```
pg_dump -D -a -t zones_seq -t interway -t "^test*" -f /tmp/zones_seq.sql <DBNAME>
```

Comment: if it was a regex, shouldn't it be `^test.*` instead of `^test*`?

Comment: It's not a regex, it uses postgres's "patterns", so it should really be `"test*"`: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PATTERNS

Comment: Not trivial to use regex, generating *invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid* error. But regular expression is correct... Only very simple regex are valid