# Ignoring a table in pg_dump and restore

Tags: postgresql

This is what I currently do to copy a database from my local machine to a remote server.

```
Dump local database:
pg_dump dbname --clean -U postgres > dumpfile

Restore remote database:
psql --single-transaction dbname -U postgres < dumpfile
```

This does a **perfect replication**.

How do I modify this to ignore particular table names, both in the source and destination?

This will be useful for tables that log website visits. I want to retain my existing remote visit logs,  while ignoring my local "visit" logs (which is just me visiting my own website locally).

Comment: duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359827/creating-a-database-dump-for-specific-tables-and-entries-postgres

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using the `-t` switch, you can be selective about what tables to include:

```
pg_dump <your switches> -t my_schema.awesome* -f backup.bat postgres
```

Which will only include those tables.

Likewise, the `-T` switch will do the opposite -- dump everything but the tables you specified:

```
pg_dump <your switches> -T my_schema.lame* -f backup.bat postgres
```

You can use each switch multiple times as well:

```
pg_dump <your switches> \
    -t my_schema.awesome* \
    -t my_schema.amazing* \
    -t my_schema.great -f backup.bat postgres
```

When you restore, it won't bother trying to restore something it didn't back up, so that part should be handled somewhat natively.