# Move one data table over from production to staging in rails with postgres?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I was wondering if anyone has a good method from copying a few tables over from production to their staging environments to keep them in sync. I'm not looking to move the entire db over and I'd like to retain some data tables on the staging environment while keeping some others in sync. Let me know if you have an approach!

Comment: Check out this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359827/creating-a-database-dump-for-specific-tables-and-entries-postgres

I think this may be the easiest way to do this, simply make a dump of the specified tables, then load it back where you want it. I would test this thoroughly before doing in production, of course.

Comment: I'll look into this, thanks for pointing it out!