# How to Export and Import Survey Data Odoo 10

Tags: postgresql, odoo

I have data in odoo survey with several table like:

- survey_survey
- survey_page
- survey_question
- survey_label
- survey_user_input
- survey_user_input_line

I Would like to export them to another database.

What should I do?

Anyone can help me, please?

Comment: [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html)

Comment: I just want to duplicate several table not one database. Is `pg_dump` can do it?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359827/